# Why do I have to explicitely define labels multiple times?

Tags: kubernetes

Why is there a need of defining one's deployment's labels multiple times? Just to explain my question fast I'll give an example.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
# 1st Time
  labels:
    app: app
    tier: backend
spec:
  selector:
# 2nd Time
    matchLabels:
      app: app
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
# 3rd time
      labels:
        app: app
        tier: backend
```

---

My first issue is that I really couldn't find any good reason for the `spec.selector.matchlabels` to exist at all. `spec.selector.matchlabels` **must match** `spec.template.metadata.labels` right?

> DESCRIPTION:
>
> Label selector for pods. Existing ReplicaSets whose pods are selected by
>      this will be the ones affected by this deployment. **It must match the pod
>      template's labels.**

So why do you have to explicitely define them, if they should be fixed to a specific value that kubernetes knows anyway and will throw an error anyways if one does not match another?

---

My second issue, which might have a more reasonable answer, is why do you have to explicitely define deployment's labels and template's labels? Aren't they supposed to match each other as well or are there any cases where they might not match to each other? Am I just using them wrong? There's no clear documentation over their use against template's labels. :/

In case I might be doing or understand something wrong please do mention! :D

Answer (score 7):

> Why is there a need of defining one's deployment's labels multiple times?

Because they are for different audiences, and they do different things. That's usually the case for when you encounter something in computers that appears to be a duplicate

I'll skip to the tl;dr before answering the rest of your questions: if *your deployments* use the same values for all 3 labels, then you can use [yaml anchors](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586) to stop the copy-paste:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels: &labels
    app: app
    tier: backend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels: *labels
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: *labels
```

> My first issue is that I really couldn't find any good reason for the spec.selector.matchlabels to exist at all. spec.selector.matchlabels must match spec.template.metadata.labels right?

The `selector:matchLabels:` must be a *subset* of the labels applied to the Pod, but they don't need to match *exactly*, otherwise it would limit the labels that **could** be applied to a Pod, since additional ones would then invalidate the `matchLabels:` and the Pod would no longer be managed by the Deployment.

> My second issue, which might have a more reasonable answer, is why do you have to explicitely define deployment's labels and template's labels? Aren't they supposed to match each other as well or are there any cases where they might not match to each other? Am I just using them wrong? There's no clear documentation over their use against template's labels. :/

The **Deployment** labels are metadata for your own use -- the kubernetes scheduler does not consult them in the slightest, to the very best of my knowledge. **Pod**s are the unit of scheduling: everything else is just accounting for the kubernetes `controller-manager` to keep track of the desired state of the world. If you wanted to be able to quickly identify all Deployments that were created by the "secops" team, you could say `kubectl get deploy -l team=secops` and it would cheerfully give you back the list. Or `release=alpha`, or `deployed-by=gitlab` or whatever. It's just metadata.

The **template** metadata is how you define labels that *will be* applied to objects which do not yet exist -- the `Deployment` is by definition describing a future state of the world, and thus you need to describe how you want things to be labeled when they are created. Then, you need to be able to describe the set of all Pods which are considered "members" of the `Deployment`. It's both possible, and I've even used it a few times, to create a **new** `Deployment` with a `selector:` which matches **existing** Pods -- and in that case, the Deployment will take over responsibility for those Pods and so long as they match the described criteria, nothing in the Pod scheduling will change, but they are, in fact, now owned by a Deployment and it will supervise them.